# 404 error on valid URL - Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a Single page application, so I only have an index file.
For some reason, I get an error 404 everytime I go directly to an "underpage".

www.domain.com works, but not www.example.com/service.

Currently I have this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
  }
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

    root /var/www/app/app;
    index index.html;
    error_page 404 /index.html;
  }
```

The first server is just to redirect the http-request to https.
I read some posts, but didn't find any solution that worked. Any tips on what I can do?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your nginx error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `error_page` directive does not change the response code. Although this *is* possible (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)), the `try_files` directive may be a better solution. For example:

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Forgot about this post. I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. Any clue what it's about?